# Retrieve the cell you used a macro in

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find the exact cell where my macro is if I press it

[image: Example]

For example, all of these pictures are the same macro. Somehow I need to find the cell where I pressed on.

I find this quite hard to explain so not sure if you will understand what I mean but it would be great if someone could help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Look into `application.caller`?

Comment: To expand: if your macro is triggered by a shape then `Application.Caller` will return the name of that shape. `Activesheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)).TopLeftCell`  will return the cell under the top-left corner of the clicked shape.

Comment: http://www.xlorate.com/excel-questions.html#Find%20Button%20Range

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Worksheet_SelectionChange event.

The Target is a range that you can access the properties of and work with.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'You can access the row and column of the target itself
    With ActiveWindow 
      .ScrollRow = Target.Row
      .ScrollColumn = Target.Column 
    End With 
End Sub
```

If you have a value in the cells with the pictures you can access that.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim str as String
    str = Target.Value
    msgbox (str)
End Sub
```